# text issue while using Persian alphabet with number in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

While using Persian text in `Text` or `TextField` compose, it won't show text in a proper way.
For example,

[image]

[image]

What should I do to handle this?

**Edit:**

for example I added simple Text:

[image]

```kotlin
Text(text = "3 بار فقط برای تستس")
```

pov: even this editor has the same issue, lol.

as you can see in this pitcure, right of string start with number; but in app, number goes to left of string, which you can see that in previous pictures.
how can I fix that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this `it wont show text in properly way`? I am not familiar with the Persian text.

Comment: Could you explain a bit, which one is expected and which one is the actual result displayed. As the stackoverflow is mainly in English, it would be nice to give some context as what is expected from the display of the Farsi text.

Comment: @Abhimanyu
so for example, I expect to see this:"3 tests to show" but instead of that, I get : "test to show 3"

Comment: @DanielBaktiar
replying ur comment, please check it out tnx

Comment: Are you using translations?

Comment: If that is the case, this is not the site for that.

Comment: @MARSK
no, I didn't. sorry if I couldn't make it clear to u...

Comment: We'd require a bit more info, sir. Try providing a minimal-reproducible-example. Something close to a code-block that we can run and check.

Comment: @MARSK
done, as you can see android studio shows right one.

Comment: Wow that's a rare thing to witness. It must be the fact that the Language is RTL and the CompositionLocalProviders provide a ltr context. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: So are you saying the problem is with the Studio Preview of your code, and not in the app? I mean, does the problem also occur when you run the app on-device?

Comment: @MARSK
yeah now u get it :)))), this happen even I run the app on device. have any idea how to handle it?

Comment: Try the answer I posted. If it doesn't work, then let know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try wrapping your text in a `CompositionLocalProvider` like so and let me know if i works.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl ) { 
      Text(...) // Check here
}
```